# Implementing Forms/Button

Tags: button, ms-access-2007

New to access and I am trying to build a database to organize some in-house parts. I currently have a table containing measurements, photos, etc and having it displayed through a form. The form would show these values and the image of said part. Id like to add two buttons to the form  that will

1. pull up a pdf of the drawing file and
2. List item processing specs.

So far I have tried creating hyperlinks or embedding the files into the form, but if you were to search for another part, it would direct me to the same two files no matter what part is displayed

I wanted to know if  was possible to make it so if you change the search for the data displayed and how to go about implementing it if it is.

Comment: When you say you tried creating hyperlinks, did you add a hyperlink field to a table? If you add a hyperlink or embedded file/object to a form it will only represent a single file.

Comment: Yes, i directed the button to a hyper link in the table, however when changing the search, it still pulls the same two files (at the top of my table) and does not change with the search criteria.

Comment: Sorry, why would a hyperlink pull *two* files? Perhaps my answer is not relevant to your situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the full circumstances of course, but typically you would add a `TextBox` control to the form that is bound to the hyperlink field in the table.

If you wish to use a `Button` instead then I would probably use the `Current` event of the form (triggered as the user moves between records) to change the hyperlink properties of the button to those of the (bound) hyperlink field. These properties are:

> Hyperlink Address, Hyperlink SubAddress and Hyperlink Target

(and the button's `Caption`)

It might require code on other events as well, to cover different eventualities.